# Can I board a flight to Canada without a passport?

Tags: visa, immigration, canada, passport, iran-citizens

I have an employer in Canada sponsor a visa for me so that I can go and work there as a skilled immigrant.

In Iran, under certain circumstances which currently apply to me, you either have to give a security deposit of about 11K USD or spend a two-year term in the military to be allowed to apply for a passport and be able to leave the country.

It should be noted that Iran and Canada have cut diplomatic relations recently and there is no active Canadian embassy in Iran.

I would like to know:

1. If I cross the border **without a passport** to a neighboring country (e.g. Iraq or Turkey), will I still be able to get a visa from the Canadian embassy over there and then buy a ticket and get on board of a flight to Canada?
2. I could leave Iran under a special passport to visit Iraq for a religious visit. Does that kind of passport do me any good here?

Comment: One way to travel internationally without a passport from your country of citizenship is to become a refugee, whereupon you will get a passport-like document from your country of refuge, but from your question it sounds like you would not qualify as a refugee.

Comment: It seems surprising to me that you got a visa without a passport. There are many scams preying upon individuals desperate for work and looking to leave there countries. You may want to double check that everything is legitimate before providing information or money to anyone.

Comment: @StrongBad, it's not clear that the OP actually has a visa. I cannot imagine Canadian immigration issuing a visa to an application w/o a passport.

Comment: @David I agree, but there are lots of scams that will provide *visa like* documents for a fee.

Comment: @StrongBad, yes, that's another possibility: that the OP has what he thinks is a visa...but isn't.

Comment: The OP does not claim to have a visa, just a sponsor.

Comment: Edited and tried to clarify that I don't have a visa yet, but to get one I have to first quit the country

Comment: Can you try a different embassy of a country which still has good diplomatic relations with Canada? It's not exactly their problem, but they just might be willing to help, as third party.

Comment: It sounds like the only real answer is already in the question: _give a security deposit of about 11K USD ... to be allowed to apply for a passport_

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I read *get on board of a plane to Canada with just my visa* as implying the OP had a visa despite being pretty sure you cannot get a Canadian visa without a passport (which is why I thought it was a scam). If however, the OP had a valid visa but no passport (e.g., lost or expired), I have no idea if Canada immigration would them to enter. You could probably pull something like that off going from Ireland to Northern Ireland or other places with open borders.

Comment: @Mast typically, a specific country is designated for that. See [protecting power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protecting_power) on Wikipedia. Canada's protecting power in Iran [is Italy](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/iran/canada-iran/canada-iran.aspx?lang=eng). But official consular responsibility for Iran [rests with Canada's mission to Turkey](https://travel.gc.ca/assistance/embassies-consulates/iran). Regardless, the application requires a passport. Even if that requirement can be waived, desire to avoid military service is probably not sufficient grounds.

Comment: @phoog thanks for the great info. And it's so horrible to waste two of my best years of life for a cause that is against my beliefs.

Comment: @azerafati I sympathize with that.  The criterion for becoming a refugee is having a "well-founded fear" of persecution for, among other reasons, political beliefs.  It's possible that the consequences you might suffer for refusing to serve, or for the beliefs you mention, would qualify you as a refugee, but I do not know for sure.  Even if it did, the process of getting to another country and getting a refugee document would likely take longer than the employer would be willing to hold the job for you.

Answer (score 19):

I'm sorry, but this is not a good plan. At a minimum you'll be stopped at these three issues:

- The purpose of the passport/travel document is to identify the individual; a visa is another country's permission for that individual to enter the country that issued the visa.  Even if you met the other requirements to obtain a visa from Canada (which are substantial: start at [this Canada government page](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/work-canada.html)), Canada won't issue a visa to a non-Canadian who doesn't have a passport or travel document.
- Unless you have a visa, and either a passport or travel document, you won't be allowed to board a flight to Canada.
- If you were allowed to board, Canadian immigration would refuse to allow you to enter the country.

Comment: It would be nice if you offered advice on what he *could* do to resolve his problem :)

Comment: @Cloud. Well the obvious thing to do would be to get travel documents sorted out.

Answer (score 5):

All immigration details aside, the Government of Canada imposes heavy fines on airlines that deliver people without appropriate documentation.   This means that no airline in the world will let you board a flight to Canada without taking responsibility to ensure that you have at least prima facie (on the surface) eligibility to enter Canada.

That is, there is almost always a final passport check at the gate, before you are allowed to board the plane.  If you can't convince the person at the gate that you're good to go, you won't board.

Comment: In many cases you can't even get a boarding pass without convincing the airline that you have the proper documents, although with the increasing popularity of online checkin, this is perhaps changing somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

I am not that informed on the policies around passports and visas, but I think the solution you might be looking for is already in your own description:

If the employer is already willing to sponsor the visa, then perhaps you could ask them to sponsor for the 11k USD deposit as well? Just make sure you explain the situation to them clearly! If they were already that willing to invest in you, then there is a good chance they'll pay for this as well. Of course this depends for how long you would work for them.

Comment: Good point, thanks for reminding me that option. Though it's a lot of money and I would definitely prefer not to be in debt for it to the employer. Plus Iran got no banking relations with the outside world, getting that amount inside is another big problem for me.